# Best way to capture text type input?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx-9

I've been struggling lately to get a text type input (e.g typing into a search bar, message bar, etc.)

I've tried using the lowest bit for `GetAsyncKeyState` (0x1), but that won't work the way I want it to. It's to slow and barely registers keystrokes. I have a keyboard class with the standard m_keys array where you just do if `m_keys[vkey]`, but that's to fast. So I tried limiting it using `GetTickCount()` and checking if `GetTickCount()` was greater than or equal to `LastStroke`. That is a little better than 0x1, but it still doesn't register some keystrokes.

What is your recommendation?

(Note this is not a console application, it's a DirectX9 application)

Comment: You can't just use `WM_CHAR` or `WM_KEYDOWN`? They work even in DirectX apps.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I switched to using SetWindowsHook(WH_KEYBOARD, &KeyHook), and this is my KeyHook callback:
http://puu.sh/jztBv/7e44e9ea60.png
How can I then convert the code to a char?

Comment: Don't you have a normal message loop? Your focus window will get keyboard messages already converted to chars if you're calling `TranslateMessage`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter oh I didn't know that, yes I have a normal window proc for my window, but how do I get the char out from that? Appreciate the help!

But damn tho, doing it in my WindowProc will just F it up for all my other classes :/

Comment: After you call `GetMessage`, call `TranslateMessage`, then your window proc will get `WM_CHAR` messages.

Comment: How about to use raw input data? (`WM_INPUT`) You will be in the lowest level, it's very fast. And you can do it together with mouse input.